# NSDate memory leak issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have a memory leak at `NSDate`. Please review the code below.

```
-(void)myMethods:(NSDate *)currentTime{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(mySecondMethods) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void) mySecondMethods{
    NSDate * currentDateTime =  [NSDate date];------->memory leak here

    for (Event * event in array) {
        if(![event checkOccur:currentDateTime]){
            return;
         } else {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:event withObject:nil];       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are calling any method in a thread you have to use Autorelease Pool.

```
-(void) mySecondMethods
{

   NSAutoReleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoReleasePool alloc] init];
   NSDate * currentDateTime =  [NSDate date];

   for (Event * event in array) {
   if(![event checkOccur:currentDateTime])
   {
      return;
   }
   else{
       [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:event withObject:nil];  

   }
   [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks 4 reply.i added nsautorelease pool but it showing leak at nsautorelease pool

Comment: You need to make sure the drain is getting called.  If 'return' it hit the pool won't drain.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) mySecondMethods{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

      NSDate * currentDateTime =  [NSDate date];

    for (Event * event in array) {
        if(![event checkOccur:currentDateTime]){
            return;
        }
        else{
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(start) toTarget:event withObject:nil];  

        }

    }
    [pool release];
  }
```